# Forward declaration causing VC++ errors, not sure how to resolve

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, include

I've looked around for a while, tried quite a few different approaches to this issue, but still cannot seem to get past errors occurring from forward declaration in a program with 3 codependent classes.

Here's a abstracted view of my current code's structure, split into 6 files + 1 main program file:

File x.h:

```
#ifndef X_H
#define X_H

using namespace std;

class y;

class x
{
    private:
        y *m_oY;
    public:
        // constructors &c
};
#endif
```

File x.cpp:

```
#include "x.h"
#include "y.h"
// Fancy stuff...
```

File y.h:

```
#ifndef Y_H
#define Y_H

using namespace std;

class z;

class y
{
    private:
        z *m_oZ;
    public:
        // constructors &c
        z *funcZ()
};
#endif
```

File y.cpp:

```
#include "y.h"
#include "z.h"
// Fancy stuff...
```

File z.h:

```
#ifndef Z_H
#define Z_H

using namespace std;

class z { ... };
#endif
```

File z.cpp:

```
#include "z.h"
// Fancy stuff...
```

File main.cpp:

```
#include "z.h"
#include "y.h"
#include "x.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { ... }
```

The first error I receive, trying to compile in VS with a clean, non-PCH, non-ATL project occurs in my implementation when trying to use Class z.  The error tells me that it's using the definition of z from y.h, and I'm not sure how to remedy this without creating a circular include problem.  Text of the error follows:

> main.cpp(114) : error C2514: 'z' : class has no constructors
>
> y.h(9) : see declaration of 'z'

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It certainly sounds like main.cpp is simply not seeing the definition of `z` in `z.h`, and only seeing a `class z;` declaration from one of the other header files. The code you posted looks fine to me, so I suspect something else funny. One way to attack problems like this is to tell the preprocessor to run without compiling, so you can see how all the #includes worked out. I don't remember offhand how to do that in Visual C++, but maybe someone else does.

Comment: does Z have constructors?  Have you tried removing the predeclaration from y.h and including z.h instead, since z doesn't appear to depend on y?

Comment: Post the code of what is done in `class z` since the error is relating to constructor. Also place all using directives in source files ( i.e., `using namespace std;` ). Remove it from headers.

Comment: Hm.  I took the files and put them in a fresh project.  I went to open the `z.h` file and to my surprise, it was empty.  That just might be the issue here.  It took a few copy-and-paste attempts to get VC to stick with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a forward declaration problem.  Main.c can see the full declaration of `class z`.  It must be that `z` has no constructor, at least of the proper shape, or maybe it is private.

Comment: Thanks for making me triple-check the header file and finding the issue.